# nextAll or similar. Readmore

Tags: jquery

Probably a fairly easy problem. Here we goes...

- Got several p-tags inside a single div
- One of the p-tags end with a "readmore" link, could be a span with a class
- Need to add a class to all following p-tags within same div
- extra classes can be added freely  of you to make solution more easy

HTML is similar to this. On page load all the p-tags after the p-tag with the "readmore" span should have a class added class="afterReadmore" or so.

```
<div>
  <p>Some lorem ipsum text</p>
  <p>
    Some lorem ipsum text
    <span class="readmore">Click</span>  <-- look for this inside a p-tag
  </p>
  <p>Some lorem ipsum text</p>           <-- add class since after p-tag with the readmore span
  <p>Some lorem ipsum text</p>           <-- add class since after p-tag with the readmore span
  <p>Some lorem ipsum text</p>           <-- add class since after p-tag with the readmore span
</div>
```

I read about the nextAll function that seem useable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('div').find('.readmore')
            .closest('p')
            .nextAll('p')
            .addClass('afterReadmore');
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/4KFWU/1/

---

You could also use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) and [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

```
$(function(){
    var index = $('div').find('.readmore').closest('p').index();
    $('div > p:gt(' + index + ')').addClass('afterReadmore');
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/4KFWU/3/

Answer (score 2):

`.nextAll` will work:

```
$('.readmore').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('p').nextAll('p').addClass('show');
});
```